# Customize jQuery collapsible menu buttons

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am new to using jQuery but I am building a mobile version of [this site](http://www.aes.co.uk). I currently have most of the theme built which can be seen [here](http://aescams.net).

What I want to do is make it look like this.

[image]

I have managed to get the header colours to change but now since I have added them to each menu item I seem to have lost my + and - icons and I am now just left with a blank dark circle. I have tried adding the data-icon="plus" and data-icon="arrow-d" but they don't appear. This is how the app looks so far.

[image]

How do I get these back ?

Answer (score 0):

The background property is the correct property to edit, however, you need to make sure that you apply it to the proper element.

The element that provides the white background is the `<a>` element below the `<h3>` element.

```
<h3 class="ui-collapsible ...">
    <a href="..." style="background: red">...</a>
</h3>
```

---

That being said, it is considered **bad practice** to use inline-styles. You should put this into an external CSS file as a class or something else and apply the styles as such.

Example CSS:

```
.red
{
    background: red;
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<h3 ...>
    <a href="..." class="red">...</a>
</h3>
```

Comment: the class that is applied to the <a> tags is ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inherit but I can't modify it as it is stored on the jQuery site here code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css

Comment: @Craig Yes but you can create your own separate CSS file and import it as well.

Comment: I tried that but could not get it to work so I created a number of different swatches in theme roller downloaded it again added the new scripts and it works ok, now I just need to style the collapsible menu buttons. Thank you for your help though :)